# How could someone induce a cave-in quickly in a medieval-ish setting?

Tags: science-based, physics, warfare, climate, geology

The idea here is that a commander of an army intentionally caves in a cave for a tactical benefit, and this needs to happen quickly. The best ideas i had were either explosives (obvious, but maybe doesn't fit a medieval setting that well.), setting fires in a ice cave, or redirecting a river to either fill (not technically a cave-in, but it fulfills the same purpose), or put too much weight on the cave roof. The river idea seems like it could take to long. Perhaps waiting for some type of weather could make sense too.

Edit: Bit unclear, i'm assuming a early 1300s european setting, without gunpowder.

Comment: Do we need to assume a natural cave? Or is an underground area with man-made supports (e.g., a mine or tunnel) also fair game?

Comment: Hello Fyren, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Many people don't realize that "medieval" can mean a classical fantasy context or any time between something like 450 a.d. and 1,450 a.d. Gunpowder was introduced to Europe during that time. It would help us if you could provide a specific context, preferably a specific date and location on Earth to use as a technology reference.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: More like about less than a quarter of it, but still some two centuries... Anyway, it is irrelevant. A commander who wants to cave in a cave for tactical advantage would have prepared the cave to cave in on command. Prepare a handy easily demolishable dam on a handy river. Thin the supporting pillars to the point where removing one is enough. Etc. There are many ways. It is purely the author's job to come up with the plot.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The answer for man-made supports is pretty easy, so i'm mainly looking for a natural cave.

Comment: @JBH That's a good point, a good benchmark might be early 1300s Europe, so no gunpowder.

Comment: Thanks! Now [edit] your question to include that year as your reference year. As a habit, never assume people will read comments to find clarifying details. Cheers!

Comment: @fyren, looking at a historical timeline of gunpowder, it was first used in Europe around 1280, so it was available in the 1300's, if still rare or not well known. https://www.timetoast.com/timelines/the-history-of-gunpowder-3afc61d6-9d39-4fce-81bf-578f2bedfe34 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_gunpowder_age In fact, being a novel compound, it might work really well as a surprise tactic.

Comment: @computercarguy good point.

Answer (score 14):

The traditional use for induced cave-in was in undermining castle walls during a siege; this was part of the job of "sappers" who would *tunnel* under the wall using wooden shoring to support the tunnel, then set a fire that would burn out the shoring and allow the tunnel to collapse and undermine (this is the origin of that word, by the way) the wall so that it, too, collapses (allowing the besieging force to bypass the defenses of the fortress).

This doesn't come close to working for a naturally formed cave, however; those are generally old enough to have stood through earthquakes, any weather phenomenon that's actually possible for their location, and a weight of overburden that won't be affected by any amount of additional material that can be piled on top in a reasonable time with medieval technology.

The one reasonable chance is, if you're in the equivalent of the 14th century or later, it might be possible to *pack the cave with gunpowder* ahead of time, and then set it off at the appropriate moment.  This will require very nearly filling the entire space, since gunpowder is far less powerful than modern explosives, but powder was used for mining almost at the same time it was used in the primitive early guns, so it's not an idea that would be "pulled out of the air" so to speak.  Additionally, this application has much less disadvantage for slower burning, more primitive forms of gunpowder (as compared to the milled, pressed, and corned powder that was made in the 19th and 20th centuries).

Comment: Good response, i wonder about the viability of two methods though. One is redirecting a river. I would think it could work, but it would take a lot of time, unless it was just removing a dam. A second method would be the fires in an ice cave. Ice caves are weakened in summer, so couldn't fires cause a similar effect?

Comment: @fyren Breaking a dam can produce an on-surface disaster, but will do little to a natural cave.  Fires in an ice cave will do less than you think -- it takes a LOT of heat to melt ice, and the water produced tends to damp or extinguish the fires.

Comment: "pack the cave with gunpowder" - the best approach is likely to dig out a few small holes in the cave wall, pack those full of gunpowder and seal those up to the greatest degree possible, to force the explosion into the wall, rather than an open explosion which will mostly expand into the air (and thus requires a much stronger explosion). Although my knowledge of gunpowder and explosion physics is limited.

Comment: @NotThatGuy *No one* had highly detailed knowledge of that kind in the 14th century.  Professional miners likely knew to pack the powder in drill holes in the rock for their purposes, but powder was still very new for them, too, prior to 1400.  Not to mention the goal here is surface collapse, not just breaking rock inside the cavern.

Comment: @ZeissIkon If you weaken the supporting walls, that seems likely to cause a cave-in. Although I don't know how much of the wall you'd need to weaken by how much to cause how big of a cave-in. Using a hole in the ceiling would probably be more effective, if more difficult (but probably not much more difficult than just using a ladder, some awkward movements and not being too emotionally attached to anyone doing the digging). Although surface collapse seems less plausible the deeper the cave is (it's not clear whether surface collapse is what was meant).

Answer (score 9):

The only quick way (assuming there is no magic involved) takes a lot of time and planning.

It involves digging out any natural supports (in the cave and at its edges) and replacing them with man made supports.  then it is only a matter of knocking out or burning the man made supports.

They used this to collapse mines during those times.  In this case, the mines were built with the man made supports preventing collapse in the first place.

This is kind of like the case of the actor who spent a decade becoming an over night success.

Comment: This being said: The expertise, tools and skilled manpower would likely already be present in any medieval army, or be available to be called upon with short notice

Answer (score 5):

**You have an army.  Use it.**

https://www.livescience.com/34608-break-stride-frequency-of-vibration.html

> In April 1831, a brigade of soldiers marched in step across England's
> Broughton Suspension Bridge. According to accounts of the time, the
> bridge broke apart beneath the soldiers, throwing dozens of men into
> the water.
>
> After this happened, the British Army reportedly sent new orders:
> Soldiers crossing a long bridge must "break stride," or not march in
> unison, to stop such a situation from occurring again.
>
> Structures like bridges and buildings, although they appear to be
> solid and immovable, have a natural frequency of vibration within
> them. A force that's applied to an object at the same frequency as the
> object's natural frequency will amplify the vibration of the object in
> an occurrence called mechanical resonance.

Your army is stationed around the cave.  Personell jump up and down in time, possibly with the help of a drummer or drum corps.  Changes in the cave according to jump frequency are watched until the frequency matching the cave's resonant frequency is identified.  The drum corps seriously gets into it and the army jumps up and down until the cave collapses.

Comment: +1 for introducing the plausibility of a tempestuous medieval haka to throw the proverbial vulgar hand gesture at your dying enemies! What is best in life? *[Chant it with me children!](https://youtu.be/LyhTxQwSwJU)*

Comment: I don't think it's plausible to cause a resonance on a cave. Caves aren't as flexible as suspension bridges.

Comment: There is no *a priori* reason that everything should have any resonant frequency, and the idea that a cave system might have one is totally implausible. If an earthquake - somewhat analogous to noise, with a wide range of frequency components - wouldn't destroy the cave through resonance, then no individual frequency of vibration within that range would, either.

Comment: @kaya3 - you are right that there is no a priori reason caves should have resonant frequencies.   And so doubters can check.  A google of "cave" and "resonant frequency" finds page upon page of articles discussing the resonant frequencies of caves.

Comment: @Willk I did your Google search and I found a mixture of pseudoscience/woo articles, and articles about acoustics (i.e. the reverberation of sound in caves), not about mechanical motion of the cave structure itself. In the latter case the resonant frequencies are in the hundreds of Hz, not frequencies that an army could jump at; and acoustical echoes resonate precisely because the sound waves *aren't* absorbed (i.e. aren't converted into heat or kinetic energy), they are reflected. So it seems physically implausible that you could collapse a cave by making continuous echoing noise.

Comment: This article seems to be talking about the movement of air and water in the cave, not the movement of the cave itself, and it only claims to be a possible explanation for the collapse (i.e. it's an unconfirmed hypothesis). Moreover this article is about the resonant frequency of a compressed air pocket (i.e. an air pocket in a flooded cave, which can act like a spring), not the resonant frequency *of* the cave; and this phenomenon could not occur in a cave that wasn't already filled with water (so it doesn't seem to be applicable in the OP's cave). Still, this is a more relevant link than ...

Comment: ... the one in your answer; I suggest including it with some explanation. (By the way, I am not the downvoter.) Oh, also, it seems the cave in question didn't exactly collapse, rather some debris fell, slid and blocked a narrow passage between the divers and the exit (though that might be good enough for the OP's purposes).

Answer (score 2):

Your settlement is on top of an old, abandoned salt mine and is supplied by a lake. The enemy commander then sends a team of sappers to dig a tunnel connecting the city's water supply to the cave. The water dissolves the salt along the walls, causing the ground to soften and everything around the hole is sucked into the cave.

The results are similar to what happened to Lake Peigneur's salt mine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Peigneur

There's a video of it. The lakeside forest and most boats on the lake were gone in less than a day.

Comment: In the Lake Peigneur case, however, the salt mine was old and had several cubic kilometers of empty space inside, so the entire contents of the lake could run into it without filling the space.  It wasn't dissolving the salt fast enough to drain the lake like a giant's bathtub.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. It's a question of mining (digging, not explosives) in the right fashion, and providing shoring (that's beams that hold up the roof) in a way that they can be easily removed.

Basically, you want a lot of rocks and such on top of the shoring, in a way when the shoring is removed the rocks fall right away. You can achieve this either by having a larger tunnel, putting in shoring, then piling rocks on it. Or by having two tunnels, one over the other, and digging in the floor of the upper one to make sure the lower one's ceiling will collapse as soon as the shoring is removed. Then the upper tunnel is blocked, hidden, etc.

If explosives are allowed, you put explosives on key locations on shoring beams. This can produce a cave in quite rapidly.

If explosives are not allowed, the prep of the shoring is more delicate. You would need to have some kind of wedge that can be removed and allow the shoring to collapse. If you are kind to your people, that happens by pulling a rope of some kind, your people being out of range of the collapse. You might also be able to do it by setting fire to the shoring beams, but that is less reliable and takes longer.

Answer (score 1):

### Hydraulic Blasting

If you can divert a river into the cave, if the cave is not able to flow the water out fast enough, then the cave experiences outwards pressure. These forces are enormous, often enough to blast an entire mountainside away. In fact, the Romans mined gold this way. The devastation has to be seen to be believed.

You do need the correct geography and very likely (but not definitely) a pipe or small aqueduct.

Answer (score 0):

If your cave has a large chasm and a narrow ledge, then destroying a section of the the narrow ledge will serve the same purpose as a cave-in, but would be easier to achieve.

Or, if your cavern has a natural vertical shaft, the army can climb up into a different passage via rope and grappling hook, then roll a boulder down into the shaft to block it.

Similarly, if you have an existing natural barrier inside the cavern like an underground river or giant chasm, you can use that as an obstacle. If so, one army can cross by boat or rope, and take their boat/rope with them, then delay the other army from crossing by firing arrows at them.

A monsoon can flood part of the cave if it starts raining.

If one party is inside the cave and the other outside, then triggering an avalanche over the cave entrance **or exit** with rock or snow is fast and relatively easy.